# NodeJS: TypeError: undefined is not a function - Promise.all - Object.keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, promise

I'd need your help because I get the typeError mentionned in the question and I'm not sure to understand why. 
I've got an object (that comes back from a request-promise) that looks like this:

```
{
                   "statusCode": 200,
                   "body": {
                      "BTC_USD": {
                         "buy_price": "4258",
                         "sell_price": "4265",
                         "last_trade": "4265",
                         "high": "4360",
                         "low": "4200",
                         "avg": "4260.2077946",
                         "vol": "219.32404491",
                         "vol_curr": "933982.49730504",
                         "updated": 1503767188
                      },
                      "BTC_EUR": {
                         "buy_price": "3640.1001",
                         "sell_price": "3650",
                         "last_trade": "3644.8",
                         "high": "3801.999999",
                         "low": "3622.000006",
                         "avg": "3685.0414084",
                         "vol": "94.48595035",
                         "vol_curr": "347993.56447153",
                         "updated": 1503767128
                      },
                      "BTC_RUB": {
                         "buy_price": "243511",
                         "sell_price": "244340",
                         "last_trade": "243511.49870226",
                         "high": "248786.99",
                         "low": "239630",
                         "avg": "243430.47675799",
                         "vol": "140.12303781",
                         "vol_curr": "34185015.26771479",
                         "updated": 1503767190
                      },
                      "BTC_UAH": {
                         "buy_price": "107000",
                         "sell_price": "107790",
                         "last_trade": "107790",
                         "high": "109900",
                         "low": "105354",
                         "avg": "108167.30195869",
                         "vol": "34.94251977",
                         "vol_curr": "3770330.73968614",
                         "updated": 1503767167
                      },
                      "DASH_BTC": {
                         "buy_price": "0.08528559",
                         "sell_price": "0.08644069",
                         "last_trade": "0.086196",
                         "high": "0.093364",
                         "low": "0.07043",
                         "avg": "0.0803689",
                         "vol": "1595.2753788",
                         "vol_curr": "123.76291968",
                         "updated": 1503767189
                      },
                   },
                   "request": {
                      "uri": {
                         "protocol": "https:",
                         "slashes": true,
                         "auth": null,
                         "host": "api.exmo.com",
                         "port": 443,
                         "hostname": "api.exmo.com",
                         "hash": null,
                         "search": null,
                         "query": null,
                         "pathname": "/v1/ticker/",
                         "path": "/v1/ticker/",
                         "href": "https://api.exmo.com/v1/ticker/"
                      },
                      "method": "GET",
                      "headers": {
                         "accept": "application/json"
                      }
                  }
                }
```

as you can see, the `body` has multiple objects and my goal is to rearrange the info in a new layout for each `body.keys`:

```
Object.keys(res.body).forEach((k) => {
          result= {
            mk: 'exmo',
            name: k,
            a: res.body[k].sell_price,
            b: res.body[k].buy_price,
            c: res.body[k].last_trade,
            v: res.body[k].vol,
            t: res.body[k].vol_curr,
            l: res.body[k].low,
            h: res.body[k].high,
            sn: res.body[k].updated,
          }
        });
        return result;
```

But for some reason it's not working... I feel like I'm not using the Promise.all properly?

Here's my full code for testing (it reproduces the error):

```
function exmo() {
  Promise.all(
    function () {
        var result = {};
        var res = {
                   "statusCode": 200,
                   "body": {
                      "BTC_USD": {
                         "buy_price": "4258",
                         "sell_price": "4265",
                         "last_trade": "4265",
                         "high": "4360",
                         "low": "4200",
                         "avg": "4260.2077946",
                         "vol": "219.32404491",
                         "vol_curr": "933982.49730504",
                         "updated": 1503767188
                      },
                      "BTC_EUR": {
                         "buy_price": "3640.1001",
                         "sell_price": "3650",
                         "last_trade": "3644.8",
                         "high": "3801.999999",
                         "low": "3622.000006",
                         "avg": "3685.0414084",
                         "vol": "94.48595035",
                         "vol_curr": "347993.56447153",
                         "updated": 1503767128
                      },
                      "BTC_RUB": {
                         "buy_price": "243511",
                         "sell_price": "244340",
                         "last_trade": "243511.49870226",
                         "high": "248786.99",
                         "low": "239630",
                         "avg": "243430.47675799",
                         "vol": "140.12303781",
                         "vol_curr": "34185015.26771479",
                         "updated": 1503767190
                      },
                      "BTC_UAH": {
                         "buy_price": "107000",
                         "sell_price": "107790",
                         "last_trade": "107790",
                         "high": "109900",
                         "low": "105354",
                         "avg": "108167.30195869",
                         "vol": "34.94251977",
                         "vol_curr": "3770330.73968614",
                         "updated": 1503767167
                      },
                      "DASH_BTC": {
                         "buy_price": "0.08528559",
                         "sell_price": "0.08644069",
                         "last_trade": "0.086196",
                         "high": "0.093364",
                         "low": "0.07043",
                         "avg": "0.0803689",
                         "vol": "1595.2753788",
                         "vol_curr": "123.76291968",
                         "updated": 1503767189
                      },
                   },
                   "request": {
                      "uri": {
                         "protocol": "https:",
                         "slashes": true,
                         "auth": null,
                         "host": "api.exmo.com",
                         "port": 443,
                         "hostname": "api.exmo.com",
                         "hash": null,
                         "search": null,
                         "query": null,
                         "pathname": "/v1/ticker/",
                         "path": "/v1/ticker/",
                         "href": "https://api.exmo.com/v1/ticker/"
                      },
                      "method": "GET",
                      "headers": {
                         "accept": "application/json"
                      }
                  }
                }
        Object.keys(res.body).forEach((k) => {
          result= {
            mk: 'exmo',
            name: k,
            a: res.body[k].sell_price,
            b: res.body[k].buy_price,
            c: res.body[k].last_trade,
            v: res.body[k].vol,
            t: res.body[k].vol_curr,
            l: res.body[k].low,
            h: res.body[k].high,
            sn: res.body[k].updated,
          }
        });
        return result;
    }).then((data) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
  })
};

exmo();
```

thanks in advance to you all for your help!

***** EDIT *****: [Trying to clarify] My objective was to get a single object per iteration of forEach. Ultimately each of these object would go into a mongo database.
I'm using incorrectly Promise.all (because it needs an array of promises) but was looking for a similar solution.

Comment: Please tell us what output you are trying to end up with.

Comment: More than "needs to be rewritten" is "just remove some line of code", https://pastebin.com/raw/znLHzvz7 Is that what you want?

Comment: `Promise.all()` should be passed an array of promises.  You are passing it a function which will never be called.  For starters, remove the `Promise.all()` entirely.

Comment: Don't use `forEach`. Also what are you trying to do with `result`?

Comment: Voting to close as this question is simply unclear and the OP is not around to clarify.

Comment: @Federkun Hey! Thanks for your answer! I'm not really looking for this though as it will yield the last result iteration ok result (or k). I'm trying to get an object out of each k to then push the info to a mongo db.

Comment: We just asked you to clarify and you were not around to do so causing lots of people to waste their time reading and attempting to understand.  That's an undesirable way to use stack overflow.  When you post, you should hang around for the next 15-30 minutes (which is your peak opportunity to get a good answer anyway) and respond immediately to any questions that arise about your post. After 30 minutes of no response, I downvoted and voted to close since it was a low quality and unclear question, not getting clarified.  Even now, you still haven't clarfied the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 If you choose to wait for half an hour before downvoting and voting to close, you only got yourself to blame for "wasting time". If a question is unclear, then just downvote and/or vote to close and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is complicated a little by your code being all lumped in together, so here I've split it up.

This function mimics your server response **as an example** to show you how the promise can be managed.

```
function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Parse the returned data
    resolve(JSON.parse(res));
  });
}
```

Then you need to transform your data. Here you can use `map` to iterate over the obj instead of `forEach`:

```
function mapData(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj.body).map((k) => {
    return {
      mk: 'exmo',
      name: k,
      a: res.body[k].sell_price,
      b: res.body[k].buy_price,
      c: res.body[k].last_trade,
      v: res.body[k].vol,
      t: res.body[k].vol_curr,
      l: res.body[k].low,
      h: res.body[k].high,
      sn: res.body[k].updated
    }
  });
}
```

Then you can simply call `getData`, `mapData`, and then output the result. You don't want `Promise.all` here because that method only accepts an array of promises.

```
getData()
  .then(mapData)
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3)));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5on338to/)** (n.b. this demo uses your parsed obj so doesn't reparse it again in `getData`).

Comment: Why are you using a promise here?  There's still no async operation shown that would benefit from a promise.  If there is an http request involved here, then it should be promisified at a lower level anyway.

Comment: In the question: "I've got an object (that comes back from a request-promise)" @jfriend00.

Comment: @jfriend00, I don't know what that second edited part of your comment means. Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: Then, if there's already a promise for the async operation, why would you create another promise.  That's an anti-pattern.  It's a bad question to start with that the OP seems to have abandoned and not clarified.  It probably should just be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: From my answer: "This function *mimics* your server response:" I'm not creating a new promise out of thin air - I'm using a simplified example of how the server responds to _then_ show how to manage that response.

Comment: Well, I guess it's impossible to make a clear answer when you have such an unclear question.  That's not what I got from your answer.  I still think you're guessing what the OP wants here since the question is so vague.  I'll leave now, since it's not worth spending any more of my time on such an unclear question.

Comment: Hey Andy! Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for... I need to give a special look at your answer to understand it fully but basically you got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, you're reassigning `result` over and over in the sane loop `forEach()`, the `return` at the end could only return the information of the last key in `body`.
What you need to do is to put all values with the same key in an array (maybe?).
Or in a simpler way: transpose the whole table.
Therefore, you gotta declare bunch of `Array`'s at the first place:

```
// init
let result = { };
let keys = ['buy_price', 'sell_price', /* etc. */];
keys.forEach(k => result[k] = []);

// gathering informations
Object.keys(res.body).forEach(name =>
    Object.keys(res.body[name]).forEach(k => result[k].push(res.body[name][k]))
);
```

Now you can easily get your information by the index from `result`.

> If you want to index'em by their original names, you can firstly initialize `result` as a bunch of `Object`'s, then use the `name` instead of directly `push()` in the inner `forEach()`.

```
Object.keys(res.body[name]).forEach(k => result[k][name] = res.body[name][k])
```

Which makes more sense on 'transposing' the whole table.

Comment: Hey @Nianyi Wang! Thanks for your answer! I'm sorry, it's my fault I guess my question was not precise enough. You got the logic but I'm looking for an outpout that would give me a new 'different' object for each result iteration. The objective being to push the info to a mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Promise.all(iterable) it take an iterable object such as an Array or String.

I modified your code, it's giving output.
Note :-  your code logic i did't not change, it give result as your logic.

```js
function exmo() {
  var data = (function () {
        var result = {};
        var res = {
                   "statusCode": 200,
                   "body": {
                      "BTC_USD": {
                         "buy_price": "4258",
                         "sell_price": "4265",
                         "last_trade": "4265",
                         "high": "4360",
                         "low": "4200",
                         "avg": "4260.2077946",
                         "vol": "219.32404491",
                         "vol_curr": "933982.49730504",
                         "updated": 1503767188
                      },
                      "BTC_EUR": {
                         "buy_price": "3640.1001",
                         "sell_price": "3650",
                         "last_trade": "3644.8",
                         "high": "3801.999999",
                         "low": "3622.000006",
                         "avg": "3685.0414084",
                         "vol": "94.48595035",
                         "vol_curr": "347993.56447153",
                         "updated": 1503767128
                      },
                      "BTC_RUB": {
                         "buy_price": "243511",
                         "sell_price": "244340",
                         "last_trade": "243511.49870226",
                         "high": "248786.99",
                         "low": "239630",
                         "avg": "243430.47675799",
                         "vol": "140.12303781",
                         "vol_curr": "34185015.26771479",
                         "updated": 1503767190
                      },
                      "BTC_UAH": {
                         "buy_price": "107000",
                         "sell_price": "107790",
                         "last_trade": "107790",
                         "high": "109900",
                         "low": "105354",
                         "avg": "108167.30195869",
                         "vol": "34.94251977",
                         "vol_curr": "3770330.73968614",
                         "updated": 1503767167
                      },
                      "DASH_BTC": {
                         "buy_price": "0.08528559",
                         "sell_price": "0.08644069",
                         "last_trade": "0.086196",
                         "high": "0.093364",
                         "low": "0.07043",
                         "avg": "0.0803689",
                         "vol": "1595.2753788",
                         "vol_curr": "123.76291968",
                         "updated": 1503767189
                      },
                   },
                   "request": {
                      "uri": {
                         "protocol": "https:",
                         "slashes": true,
                         "auth": null,
                         "host": "api.exmo.com",
                         "port": 443,
                         "hostname": "api.exmo.com",
                         "hash": null,
                         "search": null,
                         "query": null,
                         "pathname": "/v1/ticker/",
                         "path": "/v1/ticker/",
                         "href": "https://api.exmo.com/v1/ticker/"
                      },
                      "method": "GET",
                      "headers": {
                         "accept": "application/json"
                      }
                  }
                }
        Object.keys(res.body).forEach((k) => {
          result= {
            mk: 'exmo',
            name: k,
            a: res.body[k].sell_price,
            b: res.body[k].buy_price,
            c: res.body[k].last_trade,
            v: res.body[k].vol,
            t: res.body[k].vol_curr,
            l: res.body[k].low,
            h: res.body[k].high,
            sn: res.body[k].updated,
          }
        });
        return result;
    });
    
    Promise.all([data()]).then((data) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 3));
  })
};

exmo();

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Hey @Srinath! That's something I came up with as well but since I have the forEach loop, it yields the last result being iterated. That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like to generate a 'new' object out of each result iteration.